# Application crashes at seemingly completely innocous point

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms app with this Main method:

```
public Main()
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show("2");
    EnsureServiceIsInstalled();
    MessageBox.Show("4");
    LoadStationsFromConfigFile();
    MessageBox.Show("5");
}
```

There's also this method:

```
private void EnsureServiceIsInstalled()
{
   MessageBox.Show("3");
   [ ... ]
```

When run, I see messages #1 and #2 - then an exception is thrown and the program crashes.

**EDIT**:
It runs completely fine in the debugger and does not crash at all. But I have this problem if I run it outside of the debugger.

How is it possible that message #3 doesn't show before crashing?

Comment: Have you debugged this to see what goes wrong? It's also impossible to answer without detailed code to see what happens inside those calls.

Comment: where is `EnsureServiceIsInstalled` defined? same file? I see it's private...maybe you can show us more.

Comment: What's the exception? What does the stack trace show as far as where the exception actually occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if the JITter fails to JIT the `EnsureServiceIsInstalled` method; typically if it uses an assembly that the loader can't find.
This would also happen if a type initializer for any type first used in that method throws.

Wrap the outer method in a `catch` block to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: You're correct. The exception is "Could not load file or assembly..." Both Main and that private method are defined in the same file. But how could that be?...

Comment: @Eliezer: The runtime will only load an assembly when you call a method that uses a type defined in that assembly.  If you first use a type in `EnsureServiceIsInstalled`, it won't be loaded until you call that method.

Comment: that makes sense, but what can I do to fix the issue? In other words, why cannot it not find that assembly?

Comment: Make sure the assembly is there.

Comment: I think you couldn't have stated anything more obvious, but that was what made the light bulb (finally!) go on... Since I hadn't realized it was relevant I hadn't mentioned that I wasn't just running it outside of the debugger - when it crashes, I was running it after I had an installer install it. And I hadn't included that assembly's DLL!... Thank you very much!